# Kubernetes - ReplicaSet vs PodDisruptionBudget

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, replicaset

I was wondering what added value gives the PodDisruptionBudget.

As far as I understand, PodDisruptionBudget promises that a certain amount of nodes will always remain in the cluster while there are 2 options to decide how: minAvailable / maxUnavailable.

Now, when I define ReplicaSet I define how many replicas I want. So if for example I define 2, there won't be less than 2 replicas. Then what gives the PodDisruptionBudget?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`PodDisruptionBudget` helps in ensuring zero downtime for an application which `ReplicaSet` can't guarantee.

The [following post](https://medium.com/@dwdraju/poddisruptionbudget-a-key-for-zero-downtime-c478d056e373) explains with an example how `PodDisruptionBudget` can be useful in achieving zero downtime for an application:

Quoting the post, the node upgrade is a normal scenario as described in:

> Let’s consider a scenario, we need to upgrade version of node or
> update the spec often. Cluster downscaling is also a normal condition.
> In these cases, the pods running on the to-be-deleted nodes needs to
> be drained.

`kubectl drain` is performed on one of the nodes for the upgrade:

> We need to remove node1 from the pool which we cannot do it by
> detaching instantly as that will lead to termination of all the pods
> running in there which can get services down. First step before
> detaching node is to make the node unscheduled.

Running `kubectl get pods -w` will show the pods running on the node get in termination state which leads to a downtime:

> If you quickly check the pods with kubectl get pods , it will
> terminate all the running pods instantly which were scheduled on node1
> . This could lead a downtime! If you are running few number of pods
> and all of them are scheduled on same node, it will take some time for
> the pods to be scheduled on other node.

`PodDisruptionBudget` with `minAvailable` are useful in such scenarios to achieve zero downtime. `Replicaset` will only ensure that the `replicas` number of pods will be
created on other nodes during the process.

If you just have a `Replicaset` with one replica and no `PodDisruptionBudget` specified, the pod will be terminated and a new pod will be created on other nodes. This is where `PDB`s provide the added advantage over the `Replicaset`.

> For the PodDisruptionBudget to work, there must be at least 2 pods
> running for a label selector otherwise, the node cannot be drained
> gracefully and it will be evicted forcefully when grace time ends.

Comment: thanks a lot. So if PodDisruptionBudget promises zero downtime, take this scenario:
There is a Deployment with 2 replicas and defined PodDisruptionBudget minAvailable=3.
Now, there are three Nodes A B C and two replicas 1 2. The scheduler assigns replica 1 to node A and replica 2 to node B. 

Then, replica 1 is drained and scheduler moved 1 to B. So in node B now both replicas 1 + 2. Then node B is drained and my service is down.

Comment: I think new pods will be scheduled on other nodes before the pods are deleted for the drain process of node B. Also, I don't think `minAvailable=3` make sense when the number of replicas is 2.

Answer (score 0):

> Then what gives the PodDisruptionBudget?

If you have an application where you want high *availability* e.g. it may take time to rebuild a cache after each crash.

There are both [voluntary and involuntary](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/) disruptions. PodDisruptionBudget can limit the latter but both counts against the budget.

An example of *voluntary disruption* is when an employee of your platform team decide to upgrade the kernel for all your nodes - sometimes you want to do this slowly since all Pods on the node will be terminated and scheduled to a different node.

There is also *involuntary disruptions* e.g. a disk crash on one of your nodes.

Answer (score 0):

> So if for example I define 2, there won't be less than 2 replicas. Then what gives the PodDisruptionBudget?

It's 2 for minAvailable. And maxAvailable is a wrong name , it's `maxUnavailable`.